# lmer (R) and proc mixed (SAS)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, sas

Recently I have been working on replicating the results from package `lmer` in R to proc mixed in SAS for mixed modeling. There are multiple model structures that you can specify from `lmer` as explained under the link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf, page 7.

You can download the pupil_demo dataset from here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BObKK23icCKD9B-iYNCvLADOoBH6hCe_CvLrvwZwdi8/edit?usp=sharing

I have been able to replicate the results of the models `(1 | g)` and `(1 | g1) + (1 | g2)` from R to SAS for pupil_demo dataset.

1. The first question I have is about the model structure `(1 | g1/g2)` (Intercept varying among g1 and g2 within g1.) The code in R is:

```r
ach_cat_re_1 = lmer( achievement ~ ses + (1|primary_school_id) + 
    (1|primary_school_id:ses), data = pupils_demo)
ranef(ach_cat_re_1)
```

where ses is a categorical variable. in SAS I have:

```
proc mixed data=pupil;
 class ses(ref='lowest') primary_school_id; model achievement=ses/s; random intercept ses/ subject=primary_school_id s g type=vc; run;
```

I know this runs (and have verified the results match).

However, when I have a continuous predictor (age), SAS is able to estimate while R is not. The code below:

```r
ach_cat_re_1 = lmer( achievement ~ age + (1|primary_school_id) + 
    (1|primary_school_id:age), data = pupils_demo)
```

gives warning:

```r
Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: primary_school_id:age)
```

Whereas in SAS it runs

```
proc mixed data=pupil; class primary_school_id; model achievement=age/s; random intercept age/ subject=primary_school_id s g type=vc; run;
```

I am confused about why the model runs (and matches between R and SAS) when I have categorical predictor, while it cannot run in R for continuous predictor. In addition, are the results I get from SAS correct for this model?

2. The next question I have is about the model: `x + (x | g)` (correlated random intercept and slope).

R code

```r
ach_cat_re_2=lmer(achievement~1 + age + (1+age|primary_school_id), 
                  data = pupils_demo)
ach_cat_re_2=lmer(achievement~1 + ses + (1+age|primary_school_id),
                  data = pupils_demo)
```

SAS code

```
proc mixed data=pupil method=reml; class primary_school_id; model achievement=age/s; random intercept age/ type=un subject =primary_school_id s; run;
```

where age is a continuous variable. (similar code can be used for SES).

Page 67 from https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/141/mixed.pdf says that "The TYPE=UN (unstructured) option is useful for correlated random coefficient models".
In SAS the model with age is estimated, however in R it is not. (Showing the message: Warning message:

```r
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), 
   optpar, ctrl=controlpar, ctrl=controlcheckConv, :Model failed to converge 
   with max|grad| = 0.231037 (tol = 0.002, component 1)).**
```

In summary, I account these situations:

a) SAS can run with continuous predictor, R cannot.

b) SAS cannot run with categorical predictor, R can.

Is the way the models are specified correct?